# ubuntu-touch on convertible (x86, 12.04)

Tags: tablet, ubuntu-touch

I would like to test drive **ubuntu-touch** on a 12.04 based convertible notebook.
This is a normal notebook **without android** and a intel amd64 capable cpu (**not arm cpu**).

(See also the Shuttleworth presentation, e.g. http://www.heise.de/open/meldung/Ubuntu-kommt-aufs-Tablet-1806342.html)

So my questions are:

- Have someone tried this before?
- What *special* packages I have to install?
- Is there a ppa containing this packages for precise?

  - alternative: There can I find the package sources to build them for precise in my own ppa?

Any information is welcome.

Comment: I highly doubt whether it is possible easily and as of now. Since the images are targeted for ARM. Maybe some VM solution later on like androvm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Porting: 
"As Ubuntu Touch is running in a separated container on top of an Android kernel and services, the communication between them happens via Binder, Sockets and libhybris."

Ubuntu touch has a kind of Android based layer where Ubuntu Touch is working on top of it. At least for the first release this will probably the first choice so that many android models can be ported to Ubuntu Touch with reasonable effort.

But this means also that any other device which is not based on android will be very (extremely) difficult to be ported.

Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it could be possible on top of android x86 (http://www.android-x86.org/) which should run

on your laptop since it seems that ubuntu touch relays on SurfaceFlinger

(http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTMwODg) and not Xorg.

However, if you want to stick to an ubuntu base there might be an option to configure the

sources to compile linking to X or Wayland, but that depends on looking at the sources

and find a lucky answer.